# Telegram get channel Profile Photo

Tags: api, telegram

How to get current channel profile photo by channel id from telegram by api or ...?

For example my channel id is `@wikidaily` and channel link is `https://telegram.me/wikidaily`

Thx.

Comment: Nobody can help me!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

[see here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl)

You can try this function, but you would need to know at least the `InputChannel` details *(which you should already have from previous dialogue responses you had received)*:

```
 inputChannel#afeb712e channel_id:int access_hash:long = InputChannel;
```

--- Function ---

```
channels.getFullChannel#8736a09 channel:InputChannel = messages.ChatFull;
```

It will return :

```
messages.chatFull#e5d7d19c full_chat:ChatFull chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = messages.ChatFull;
```

Which contains `full_chat:ChatFull` of type `ChatFull` from this you can extract the photo you require: `chat_photo:Photo`

```
channelFull#c3d5512f flags:# can_view_participants:flags.3?true can_set_username:flags.6?true id:int about:string participants_count:flags.0?int admins_count:flags.1?int kicked_count:flags.2?int read_inbox_max_id:int read_outbox_max_id:int unread_count:int chat_photo:Photo notify_settings:PeerNotifySettings exported_invite:ExportedChatInvite bot_info:Vector<BotInfo> migrated_from_chat_id:flags.4?int migrated_from_max_id:flags.4?int pinned_msg_id:flags.5?int = ChatFull;
```

If I can find a simpler direct method, i will update this post.

cheers.